# How can I efficiently calculate bits/bytes per second with a loop?

Tags: python, bash, loops, type-conversion

I'm trying to calculate bits/bytes/kilobytes/megabytes per second in a python / bash script, I don't know which one is more sufficient.

I was thinking about writing a loop which checks wether the download duration is more than one second, and if so, count how many miliseconds its shy off the 'one second' and then apply this somehow to my downloaded size to recieve my MB/s result. I don't know if this is the best solution or if this is even close.
The first variable is the amount downloaded (file size)
The second variable is the duration in seconds.

```
1MB;0,127
2MB;0,563
3MB;0,655
```

Am I going in the right direction with my idea or is there a different (more sufficient) method?

Comment: Please explain the context of this calculation and show us what you have tried so far!

Comment: Im trying to calculate mbps download speed with a loop so I can use this in a script to measure download statistics. So far I only have the idea I talked about, im wondering if i'm going in the right direction

Comment: wouldn't `file size / overall duration` be easier?

Comment: Does this result in a 'per second' measurement? I'd like to throw the results in a graph later, there are different kinds of download sizes, so I dont want to conflict / mix them up